# In r, how do I make my function recognize a specific letter as the unknown value that I want it to solve for?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am just trying to write a simple function where the user will input 2 known sides of a right triangle and then the output will be the length of the third side. I have it working with a "fix" but it's a duct tape solution. The idea is that the user will be able to call on my function, named pythag. I want them to be able to enter in values by typing pythag(3,b,5). This would tell the program that one leg of the triangle is length 3, the hypotenuse is length 5, solve for the other leg, leg b. But the only way I've gotten it to work is if the user types in pythag(3, "b", 5). Here is the code:

```
pythag <- function(a, b, c) {
    if (a %in% "a") {
            answer <- sqrt(c^2 - b^2)
    } else if ( b %in% "b") {
            answer <- sqrt(c^2 - a^2)
    } else if (c %in% "c") {
            answer <- sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
    }
    answer }
```

If I take away the "" in the code so that it is stated as (a %in% a), it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I've also tried (a==a) and (a=a).

Comment: I think you're getting a bit confused with the name and the value of a variable. In `function(a, b, c)`, `a` is the variable *name* (you could've also named it e.g. `x1`). You test the *value* with e.g. `a == "a"`, and so on. You don't need `%in%` if you're testing for the equality of two values.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to design your function this way, since the labels of triangle sides are largely arbitrary. But if you insist, I would approach it this way:

```
pythag <- function(A=NA, B=NA, C=NA) {
  # want to check inputs
  inputs <- c(A, B, C)
  if (sum(is.na(inputs)) != 1)
    stop("Exactly two inputs are required!")
  if (is.na(A)) return(sqrt(C^2 - B^2))
  if (is.na(B)) return(sqrt(C^2 - A^2))
  if (is.na(C)) return(sqrt(A^2 + B^2))
}
pythag(A=3, B=4)
[1] 5
pythag(A=3, C=5)
[1] 4
pythag(B=4, C=5)
[1] 3
```

Of course, this function is still not great, since it is not "immune" from bad inputs. But it should generally work for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out. I see what you mean about the labels of sides being arbitrary. The only purpose I had in writing this code was to get myself started in building a function and getting the hang of using if, else commands. As I mentioned, I am new to R and figured the best way to get the hang of it was to just tinker. Your code has given me several new ideas, such as applying the is.na command with your inputs variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This answer relies on your users naming the known inputs. It then spits out the name and value of the unknown input.

```
# Create the Pythageorean Theorem function
# A squared + B squared = C squared
PythagoreanTheorem <- function( a = NULL, b = NULL, c = NULL ){
  # Takes in two inputs and calculates 
  # the missing parameter's value

  # Args: two numeric values

  # Stop messages
  if( !is.null( x = a ) &&
      !is.null( x = b ) &&
      !is.null( x = c ) ){
    stop( "All three arguments cannot be used. Use two.")
  }

  if( !is.numeric( x = a ) && !is.null( x = a ) | 
      !is.numeric( x = b ) && !is.null( x = b ) |
      !is.numeric( x = c ) && !is.null( x = c ) ){
    stop( "Ensure both inputs are numeric.")
  }

  if( !is.null( a ) && !is.null( b ) ){

    return( 
      setNames( 
        object = sqrt( x = c( a^2 + b^2 ) )
        , nm = "c"
      )
    )

  } else if( !is.null( a ) && !is.null( c ) ){

    return( 
      setNames( 
        object = sqrt( x = c( a^2 + c^2 ) )
        , nm = "b"
      )
    )

  } else if( !is.null( b ) && !is.null( c ) ){

    return( 
      setNames( 
        object = sqrt( x = c( b^2 + c^2 ) )
        , nm = "a"
      )
    )
  }

} # end of PythagoreanTheorem() function

# test PythagoreanTheorem() function
PythagoreanTheorem( c = 3, a = 4 )
# b 
# 5 
class( x = PythagoreanTheorem( c = 3, a = 4 ) )
# [1] "numeric"
PythagoreanTheorem( a = 2, b = 5, c = 6)
# Error in PythagoreanTheorem(a = 2, b = 5, c = 6) : 
#   All three arguments cannot be used. Use two.

# end of script #
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a slightly different user interface:

```
pythag <- function(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(a), is.numeric(b), is.numeric(c), (a!=0) + (b!=0) + (c!=0) == 2)
  if (c == 0) sqrt(a^2 + b^2) else sqrt(c^2 - a^2 - b^2)
}

# tests

pythag(a = 3, c = 5)
## [1] 4
pythag(3,,5) # same
## [1] 4

pythag(a = 4, b = 3)
## [1] 5
pythag(4, 3) # same
## [1] 5

pythag(3, "X")
## Error: is.numeric(b) is not TRUE

pythag(1)
## Error: (a != 0) + (b != 0) + (c != 0) == 2 is not TRUE

pythag(1, 2, 3)
## Error: (a != 0) + (b != 0) + (c != 0) == 2 is not TRUE
```